# Interface and Generics Type Mismatch - Required Nothing

Tags: kotlin, generics

**Summary:**

- Type Mismatch when using Generics and Star Projection
- Needed Type is a Generic as well - Nested Generic?
- Reproducible Code Below

**Question:**

My intent is to be able to use and extend an interface and the various functions across different custom types.

I have been able to refactor the interface in order to be used with Generics, but I am now unable to use the functions that I have updated.

How am I able to continue with the updated interface and be able to use the functions properly?

I have seen some other options in other questions to be able to directly use the Type you want.
I expect to set the 'sorter' to different options/strategies and so set the 'sorter' to different types/subclasses. I would assume then that if I was to hardcode a type to be used that I wouldn't be able to use the needed type. Needing then to create as many type objects as there are types to use anything.

I am having trouble with this as the needed type is itself a generic, `interface Repo<T>`. When I use the type through the subclass it is finding the subclass as the type being used, but it is requesting the actual interface type. I am not sure which type to use or how to use it due to that additional  generic being used.

I assume that it wants to hardcode the generic type (T) inside of the generic type (Repo). I'm not sure then how to set the strategy of the sorter if it is hardcoded to the one set of types.

What else is possible?

**Minimum Reproducible Code**

```
interface Repo<T> {

    fun findAll(): Array<T>
}
data class CustomRepo(val num: Int) : Repo<String> {

    override fun findAll(): Array<String> {
        return arrayOf("Sorted1, Sorted2, $num")
    }
}
class SortOrderObject : SortOrder<Repo<Any>> {

    override fun calcSort(repo: Repo<Any>): String {
        val total = repo.findAll()
        return total.toString()
    }
}
interface SortOrder<Repo> {

    fun calcSort(repo: Repo): String
}
fun main() {
    val sorter: SortOrder<Repo<Any>> = SortOrderObject()
    val orderString = sorter.calcSort(CustomRepo(3))
// Type mismatch: inferred type is CustomRepo but Repo<Any> was expected
    println(orderString)
}
```

Comment: Why did you declare `val sorter: SortOrder<*>` instead of `val sorter: SortOrder<CustomRepo>`? You seem to want `sorter` to also be a `SortOrder<String>` or `SortOrder<SomeOtherType>`, so why did you expect `sorter.calcSort(CustomRepo(3))` to work at all? If `sorter` happens to be a `SortOrder<SomeOtherType>`, you would have given it the wrong type of object.

Comment: Thanks. yes you are right to question this. This is test code for me to better understand what is going on and so might not make all that much sense. Originally I did have what has been suggested, as the code only required the one type. What is extra now is how to extend to different types and be able to use the similar functions. The pain now is not being able to use either the subclass (SortOrderObject) or the interface type itself (Repo<T>). I'm not sure which one to use or use something else and/or how to use the 'nested generic' properly.

Comment: To actually answer your question... `calcSort` would grab the data that needs to be sorted from a custom data type. I would expect that `CustomRepo` shouldn't be the wrong type of object and should be within the scope of the parent interface or subclass. The problem, at least in my mind, is how and where to use the correct interface or subclass and how to then implement it to actually do the function required. If I was to use the 'correct' type, it is Repo<T> and so wouldn't work properly. How would I be able to use Repo<T> in order to define a proper type instead of <*>?

Comment: I *think* what you need here is a covariant (`out`) `T` in `Repo<T>`. Then you can pass a `Repo<String>` to a `Repo<Any>`. That said, can you show another `Repo` implementation, and another `SortOrder` implementation? Right now there is only a `SortOrder<Repo<Any>>` and a `Repo<String>`. Since your question is about being able to assign any type of `SortOrder` to `sorter` (I think?), it would help clarify things if you showed multiple implementations of `SortOrder`. e.g. would there be a `SortOrder<Repo<Int>>` implementation? Would you want that to be assigned to `sorter`?

Comment: Thanks. Yes. I agree with you and alongside the other answer that 'out' is needed. The current problem is that I am unsure about how to adapt the code to complete multiple different types and then be able to properly set the `SortOrder`. There would be custom types but with similar `ArrayList<String>` variables that would hold the information needed. So no it is not every type, but a subset of Repo. It might just be `SortOrder<Repo<DataList1>>` `SortOrder<Repo<DataList2>>`, which each hold their own list of strings, with different functionality. Would there be a way to use concrete classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made `SortOrder` accept the return type, and `calcSort(repo: Repo<out T>)` will wrap the return type to accept `Repo<T>`:

```
interface Repo<T> {
    fun findAll(): Array<T>
}

data class CustomRepo(val num: Int) : Repo<String> {
    override fun findAll(): Array<String> {
        return arrayOf("Sorted1, Sorted2, $num")
    }
}

class SortOrderObject<T> : SortOrder<T> {
    override fun calcSort(repo: Repo<out T>): String {
        val total = repo.findAll()
        return total.joinToString()
    }
}

interface SortOrder<T> {
    fun calcSort(repo: Repo<out T>): String
}

fun main() {
    val sorter: SortOrder<Any> = SortOrderObject()
    val orderString = sorter.calcSort(CustomRepo(3))
    println(orderString)
}
```

Marked `Repo` type as `out` to make it work with `CustomRepo`

Please notice that I've changed `toString()` to `joinToString()`, to output array data correctly

Comment: Thank you. I think my problem might be a bit more complicated than what I have put down. The only difference is that the CustomRepo is inherited by another Generic Interface. `class SortOrderObject : SortOrder<Repo<T>>` Maybe I then need to create an interface for my data types as well... Would this be a better way? Is there something better?

Comment: I have just tried this. It works for my example but for real code it is not exactly working. I will try to get something reproducible. The problem is that `interface Repo<T>` doesn't seem to work well with the functions. Where I would expect a `T`, it is now expecting a subclass. So I would have to duplicate the different interfaces for each different type. Not sure if this is the intended effect.

Comment: extra code added in 'response' section at the bottom of my question

Comment: I've updated the code for your requirements. Please check if it looks good for you.

Comment: Thanks. This is working better. I still have some trouble with the initial call in my production code, similar to the test code `val sorter: SortOrder<Any> = SortOrderObject()`. It works fine for the instances and different objects, but is not allowing me to be able to use it for Any objects in the main class. `Type mismatch: inferred type is SortOrderObject but SortOrder<Any> was expected`. I will see if there is a way to reproduce this in the test code.

Comment: The problem is that when I try to make the SortOrderObject concrete to the data type that I need it to be. `class SortOrderObject : SortOrder<CustomRepo>` Maybe I am not using this correctly. Is there something that can be done with this, or do I need to give more information? Same 'type mismatch' as in the last comment.

Comment: Thanks. It took me a while to refactor the rest of the application as it impacted a line of different features. I have now been able to test it. It is working and much cleaner code. I needed to create a couple different Abstract Factories in order to be able to use the different `sorter`s per type. I will accept this answer as the most correct due to the practical code examples. Thanks for your support.